# Difference between confidence and accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In machine learning, is confidence nothing different than accuracy? Or there is any significant difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In learning algorithm, Confidence defines the probability of the event (or probability of input to fall in different classes). If a class has high probability then it has high confidence. Confidence value can be calculated for single input as well giving the meaning as how much the algorithm is confident for that class.

On the other hand, accuracy defines the skill of the learning algorithm to predict accurately. It defines the percentage of correct predictions made from all predictions.

But most of the time so people use these terms as of same meaning.

[some information about Accuracy and confidence](https://machinelearningmastery.com/report-classifier-performance-confidence-intervals/)